# Raw sql to json in Django, with Datetime and Decimal MySql columns

Tags: python, mysql, json, django

I am using Ajax to make some requests from client to server, I am using DJango and I have used some Raw Sql queries before, but all of my fields was Int, varchar and a Decimal, for the last one I had an enconding problem, but I overrided the "default" property of Json and everything worked.

But that was before, now I have a query wich gives me Decimal and DateTime fields, both of them gave me enconding errors, the overrided "default" doesn't work now, thats why with this new one I used `DjangoJSONEncoder`, but now I have another problem, and its not an encoding one, I am using `dictfetchall(cursor)` method, recomended on Django docs, to return a dictionary from the Sql query, because `cursor.fetchall()` gives me this error: `'tuple' object has no attribute '_meta'`.

Before I just sended that dictionary to `json.dumps(response_data,default=default)` and everything was fine, but now for the encoding I have to use the following: `json.dumps(response_data,cls=DjangoJSONEncoder)` and if I send the dictionary in that way, I get this error:

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
```

And if I try to use the serializers, like this:

```
response_data2= serializers.serialize('json', list(response_data))
```

And later send `response_data2` to `dumps`, I get this error:

```
'dict' object has no attribute '_meta'
```

This is the code for the MySql query:

```
def consulta_sql_personalizada(nombres,apellidos,puesto):
    from django.db import connection, transaction
    cursor = connection.cursor()

    cursor.execute("""select E.idEmpleado as id,CONCAT(Per.nombres_persona,' ',Per.apellidos_persona) as nombre,P.nombre_puesto as puesto,E.motivo_baja_empleado as motivo_baja,E.fecha_contratacion_empleado AS fecha_contratacion,E.fecha_baja_empleado as fecha_baja, SUM(V.total_venta) AS ventas_mes,E.fotografia_empleado as ruta_fotografia from Empleado as E
                      inner join Puesto as P on E.Puesto_idPuesto=P.idPuesto
                      inner join Venta as V on V.vendedor_venta=E.idEmpleado
                      inner join Persona as Per on E.Persona_idPersona=Per.idPersona
                      where (Per.nombres_persona like %s OR Per.apellidos_persona like %s OR E.Puesto_idPuesto=%s)
                      AND E.estado_empleado=1 AND V.estado_venta=1
                      AND
                      (YEAR(V.fecha_venta) = YEAR(Now())
                      AND MONTH(V.fecha_venta) = MONTH(Now()))""",[nombres,apellidos,puesto])
    row = dictfetchall(cursor)
    return row
```

And this is the last part of the view that makes the query and send it to ajax using json:

```
        response_data=consulta_sql_personalizada(rec_nombres,rec_apellidos,rec_puesto)
        return HttpResponse(
            json.dumps(response_data,cls=DjangoJSONEncoder),
            content_type="application/json"
        )
        else:
        return HttpResponse(
            json.dumps({"nothing to see": "this isn't happening"}),
            content_type="application/json"
        )
```

What I want to know is, how can I parse the raw sql result to Json using that enconding?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, was my bad, i'm using JQuery ajax method, and in the "success" part I forgot to stop using `json.parse` to print the data in the console, the data was json already, that's why I had that `line 1 column 1 error`. My code worked exactly like it was posted here. If someone want to know how to make asynchronous requests, I followed this tutorial: [Django form submissions using ajax](https://realpython.com/blog/python/django-and-ajax-form-submissions/)